# box-shadow color requires the position values?

Tags: css

I am experimenting with some stuff with CSS and discovered that the *box-shadow*'s color value only works when by its position values' side.

Works like this

```
.myDiv{ box-shadow:0 0 4px #666; }
.myOtherDiv{ box-shadow:0 0 4px #666; }
```

Doesn't work like this

```
.myDiv{ box-shadow:0 0 4px; }
.myOtherDiv{ box-shadow:0 0 4px; }
.myDiv, .myOtherDiv{ box-shadow:#666; }
```

**Is this true to you too?**

Comment: That's because the default values are 0 0 0. You're not actually making a shadow this way, just assigning a color (to nothing).

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought from what I read o the documentation, just wanted to check if my thoughts where on the right way, thanks ;)